# Vim Function: How to get text between double quotes?

Tags: vim, function

Want to add a function in the `.vimrc` to auto get the text between double quotes.

If current line is

```
add_file -vhdl -lib work "../src/abc.vhd"
```

The function will get `../src/abc.vhd`

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: `f"yi"` in normal mode will get that content in register `"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward solution is yanking the *inner double-quotes* text object (as per @muru's comment): First move inside the quote with `f"`, then `yi"`.

Alternatively, you can use lower-level functions to extract a pattern from the current line:

```
:echo matchstr(getline('.'), '"\zs[^"]\+\ze"')
```

This doesn't change cursor position, doesn't clobber registers.

What's better depends on the *use* of the text.

Comment: Hi, what if yank inner single-quotes text? Or could you explain how [^"] works? Thanks!

Comment: echo matchstr(getline('.'), "'\\zs[^']\\+\\ze'") get from https://gitter.im/neoclide/coc-cn